# UIView is not changing correctly the color values SWIFT

Tags: swift, uicolor

I want my app to start with a color in the view but when I add the UIColor values to the ViewDidLoad I change the color to white! and not the red color I want to add. Here is my code, I have checked all the code but am kind of programming in swift so I don't find something that is not getting the work done:

```
class RGBViewController: UIViewController {
    //Sldiers
     @IBOutlet weak var redSlider: UISlider!
     @IBOutlet weak var greenSlider: UISlider!
     @IBOutlet weak var blueSlider: UISlider!
     //Labels
     @IBOutlet weak var redLabel: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var greenLabel: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var blueLabel: UILabel!
     //View
     @IBOutlet weak var colorView: UIView!

    //set the thumb image
    func changeThumbImage() {
        let redThumb = UIImage(named: "RedSmall")
        redSlider?.setThumbImage(redThumb, forState: .Normal)
        let greenThumb = UIImage(named: "GreenSmall")
        greenSlider?.setThumbImage(greenThumb, forState: .Normal)
        let blueThumb = UIImage(named: "BlueSmall")
        blueSlider?.setThumbImage(blueThumb, forState: .Normal)
    }

    //VIEW DID LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        changeThumbImage()
        updateBackgroundColor()
        colorView.backgroundColor! = UIColor(red: 226, green: 67, blue: 67, alpha: 1)
    }

    func colorValues() {
        //assign the Int value to the labels
        redLabel?.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: Int(redSlider.value * 255))
        greenLabel?.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: Int(greenSlider.value * 255))
        blueLabel?.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: Int(blueSlider.value * 255))
    }

    @IBAction func updateBackgroundColor() {
        colorValues()
        //safe unwrap the sliders and assign the view color
        if let red = redSlider, green = greenSlider, blue = blueSlider{
            let redValue = CGFloat(red.value)
            let greenValue = CGFloat(green.value)
            let blueValue = CGFloat(blue.value)

            colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1)
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to divide the color value with 255

```
UIColor(red: 226/255.0, green: 67/255.0, blue: 67/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

With your action also :

```
@IBAction func updateBackgroundColor() {
    colorValues()
    let redValue = CGFloat(redSlider.value)
    let greenValue = CGFloat(greenSlider.value)
    let blueValue = CGFloat(blueSlider.value)

    colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redValue/255.0, green: greenValue/255.0, blue: blueValue/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

I have created sample :

```
@IBOutlet var colorView: UIView!
@IBAction func chageSlider(sender: UISlider!) {
    println(sender.value)
    self.colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(sender.value)/255.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

`changeSlider` is `valueChanged` action of the `UISlider`

Connect your slider with @IBAction

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Now the view is black and it won't change even if I move the sliders to change the color

Comment: @Pixele9 added one sample and its working for me. hope it will help you. use the valueChanged action/event of the slider.

Comment: What is the action/event? haha sorry I don't know

Comment: Sorry! And thank you soooo much to for helping me I am just 15 years old and trying to figure this out so... Well now the view appears with the red color I want but when I change the slider value it goes back to black.

Comment: @Pixele9 Don't worry. Learn and Keep it up. http://makeapppie.com/2014/10/02/swift-swift-using-color-and-uicolor-in-swift-part-1-rgb/